Calculating ROGUE score between Reference summary and prediction summary
I am trying to compute ROGUE score between AI generated summary and Human written summary as described below. My summary length for both will be greater than 50 tokens. Here is my python code.
pip install rouge_score
from rouge_score import rouge_scorer

prediction = "I am ABC. I have completed my bachelor's degree in computer application at XYZ University and I am currently pursuing my master's degree in computer application through distance education."

reference = "I'm ABC. I have finished my four-year certification in PC application at XYZ and I'm currently pursuing my graduate degree in PC application through distance training."


scorer = rouge_scorer.RougeScorer(['rouge1', 'rouge2', 'rougeL', 'rougeLsum'])
scores = scorer.score(reference, prediction)
# Print the scores
for key in scores:
    print(f'{key}: {scores[key]}')

Output:
rouge1: Score(precision=0.6129032258064516, recall=0.6551724137931034, fmeasure=0.6333333333333333)

rouge2: Score(precision=0.3333333333333333, recall=0.35714285714285715, fmeasure=0.3448275862068965)

rougeL: Score(precision=0.6129032258064516, recall=0.6551724137931034, fmeasure=0.6333333333333333)

rougeLsum: Score(precision=0.6129032258064516, recall=0.6551724137931034, fmeasure=0.6333333333333333)

I am new to this field. So I am not sure which Rogue score to consider for my use case and it' significance.
